# resources and references for RSPEC

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I've started learning Rails3 / rspec recently, and I'm finding I'm spending about 80% of my time trying to figure out how to do basic things in rspec. I'm continuously frustrated by the lack of good rspec resources, at least ones that I've found so far, and I'm sure there must be a better way to learn.

Does anyone know of any good rspec resources? This includes tutorials and guides, but I'm particularly after a good reference for methods and classes.

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check out [The RSpec Book](http://davidchelimsky.net/) by David Chelimsky

I've heard there is an e-book floating around the Internet...